# Identifying color properties from CSS and combine selectors?

Tags: css, optimization, code-cleanup

I'm looking for a tool that helps me to identify CSS color properties (color, background-color, border-color etc.) and combined the selectors instead of repeating the color property over and over.

so a code like this:

```
body {color: #656565;}        
a {color: #c0c0c0;}        
h1 {color: #000;}

.norm-element {color: #656565;}    
.accent-element {color: #c0c0c0;}
```

would end:

```
body, .norm-element {
    color: #656565;
}

a, .accent-element {
    color: #c0c0c0;
}

h1 { color: #000; }
```

Comment: I'm not sure there's a tool that does exactly what you want, but I have had some success using clean-css to optimize and merge rules https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css

Answer (score 1):

You could use css variables. Resources [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) and browser support which is pretty good [here](https://caniuse.com/css-variables).
 So from your example

```
body {color: #656565;}        
a {color: #c0c0c0;}        
h1 {color: #000;}
.norm-element {color: #656565;}    
.accent-element {color: #c0c0c0;}
```

becomes

```
  :root {
    --main-bg-color: #656565;
  }
  body, .norm-element {
    color: var(main-bg-color);
   }
```